# Proper way of sorting Java beans by multiple fields

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

We have code with complex Comparators that have been used for sorting java objects throughout our application. Historically these have worked, but since the introduction of TimSort in Java 7 we occasionally get the **Comparison method violates its general contract!** error.. depending on what data is held within the object.

Here is an example of one of our legacy Comparators (which could be almost a decade old - excuse the dodgyiness):

```
 public int compare(TemplateBean b1, TemplateBean b2) {

  // avoid null pointer exceptions
  if (b1 == null && b2 == null) return 0;
  if (b1 == null) return 1;
  if (b2 == null) return -1;

  int cmp = 0;
  if ("UNATTACHED".equals(b1.getStatusCode()) &&
     !"UNATTACHED".equals(b2.getStatusCode())) {
     cmp = 1;
  }
  if (!"UNATTACHED".equals(b1.getStatusCode()) &&
     "UNATTACHED".equals(b2.getStatusCode())) {
     cmp = -1;
  }
  if (!"UNATTACHED".equals(b1.getStatusCode()) &&
     !"UNATTACHED".equals(b2.getStatusCode()) &&
     !"FIELDSIMPLE".equals(b1.getRefRltshpTypeCode()) &&
     !"FIELDSIMPLE".equals(b2.getRefRltshpTypeCode()) &&
     !"CUSTOM".equals(b1.getRefRltshpTypeCode()) &&
     !"CUSTOM".equals(b2.getRefRltshpTypeCode()) &&
     !"FUNCTION".equals(b1.getRefRltshpTypeCode()) &&
     !"FUNCTION".equals(b2.getRefRltshpTypeCode())) {
     String parent1 = b1.getGroupCode() == null ? "" : b1.getGroupCode().toUpperCase();
     String parent2 = b2.getGroupCode() == null ? "" : b2.getGroupCode().toUpperCase();
     cmp = parent1.compareTo(parent2);
  }

  if (cmp == 0) {
     Integer i1 = b1.getSortOrder() == null ? Const.ZERO : b1.getSortOrder();
     Integer i2 = b2.getSortOrder() == null ? Const.ZERO : b2.getSortOrder();
     cmp = i1.compareTo(i2);
  }

  if (cmp == 0) {
     String s1 = b1.getShortDescription();
     if (s1 == null) s1 = "";
     String s2 = b2.getShortDescription();
     if (s2 == null) s2 = "";
     cmp = s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
  }

  return cmp;  }
```

So, I want to replicate this functionality, but with a Comparator that is safe for use with TimSort.

From the code you can see that there a multiple levels to this comparison..

1. It will compare the group codes.
2. If Group codes are the same it will compare sort order.
3. If Sort order is the same it will compare description.

Which means it will return the result of the compare at a particular level. Which might be the comparison result of two strings or two integers. I think this is what is breaking the TimSort.

The only way I have been able to make this Comparator work around the General Contract issue is by hashing the contents of the bean and performing a string comparison. Other ideas have included writing our own sorting function.. Surely there is a better way?

Should the bean be constructed in another way to support this?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with TimSort, but one thing that might help you is implementing some kind of enumeration for the fields that you're comparing instead of trying to do complex string comparison operations.  I'm not sure if that's a good way to fix this, but it's one thought I had.

Comment: There is way too much string comparison going on here.  You should really be converting the strings to corresponding numbers or something and comparing those rather than trying to dig through these messy conditions.

Comment: I don't think that the problem is related to how a comparison is determined (using strings or enumerations), I think it has more to do with the fact that TimSort has this restriction:

**The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: ((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0)) implies compare(x, z)>0.**

Which means that if X and Y are at compared at the same level, but Y and Z are at compared at different levels, the returned integer may break this rule. I need to return a value that represents order, but also doesn't break the X > Y > Z rule.

Comment: From a first glance I would say that the problem is somewhere inside the 3rd `if`(excluding the null checks).  The last two seem unproblematic because they use string and integer comparisons and those are already transitive.  I'll look at it closer once I have more time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with the above `Comparator` is that it is not transitive. It may seem to 'work' on older JDKs because they didn't provide detection for broken comparators, but it just couldn't work correctly in general case and buggy behavior was not revealed until JDK 7.

The source of its non-transitiveness is in conditional comparison on `groupCode` property.
Consider situation when comparator orders objects A and B as A < B due to `sortOrder` field omitting comparison by `groupCode` because `"FUNCTION".equals(B.getRefRltshpTypeCode())` and 
objects B and C are ordered as B < C due to `sortOrder`. But it is possible that A and C when compared directly are ordered as C < A due to `groupCode` comparison. And this breaks transitivity requirement for `Comparator`.

To fix this problem `groupCode` should be always taken into account and every object for which `groupCode` is skipped due to `refRltshpTypeCode` value should be treated for example as smaller than any object for which `groupCode` is now used for comparison.

Compare method should looks something like (this is just to give you the idea):

```
public int compare(TemplateBean b1, TemplateBean b2) {

    // avoid null pointer exceptions
    if (b1 == null && b2 == null) return 0;
    if (b1 == null) return 1;
    if (b2 == null) return -1;

    int cmp = 0;
    if ("UNATTACHED".equals(b1.getStatusCode()) &&
       !"UNATTACHED".equals(b2.getStatusCode())) {
        cmp = 1;
    }
    if (!"UNATTACHED".equals(b1.getStatusCode()) &&
       "UNATTACHED".equals(b2.getStatusCode())) {
       cmp = -1;
    }

    if (shouldBeComparenByGroupCode(b1) != shouldBeComparedByGroupCode(b2)) {
        if (!shouldBeComparenByGroupCode(b1)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
           return 1;
        }
    }

    if (shouldBeComparenByGroupCode(b1) && shouldBeComparenByGroupCode(b2)) {
        String parent1 = b1.getGroupCode() == null ? "" : b1.getGroupCode().toUpperCase();
        String parent2 = b2.getGroupCode() == null ? "" : b2.getGroupCode().toUpperCase();
        cmp = parent1.compareTo(parent2);
    }

    if (cmp == 0) {
        Integer i1 = b1.getSortOrder() == null ? Const.ZERO : b1.getSortOrder();
        Integer i2 = b2.getSortOrder() == null ? Const.ZERO : b2.getSortOrder();
        cmp = i1.compareTo(i2);
    }

    if (cmp == 0) {
        String s1 = b1.getShortDescription();
        if (s1 == null) s1 = "";
        String s2 = b2.getShortDescription();
        if (s2 == null) s2 = "";
        cmp = s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }

    return cmp;
}
```

where

```
private static boolean shouldBeComparenByGroupCode(TemplateBean b1) {
     return !"UNATTACHED".equals(b1.getStatusCode()) &&
            !"FIELDSIMPLE".equals(b1.getRefRltshpTypeCode()) &&
            !"CUSTOM".equals(b1.getRefRltshpTypeCode()) &&
            !"FUNCTION".equals(b1.getRefRltshpTypeCode());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19540979/97627) from @RomanKonovai is correct, however adding some more details.

Think about how the code compares these three objects, and assume that all non-reference:

```
               A          B          C
Status         UNATTACHED UNATTACHED UNATTACHED
RefRltshpType  CUSTOM     FUNCTION   CUSTOM
Group          Cat        Ball       Apple
SortOrder      10         20         30
```

Going through the implementation in the question, we can see that A < B, and B < C, and C < A. In other words `A < B < C < A`, or `A < A`. This is clearly not logical, and happens since depending on the values of `Status` and `RefRltshpType` the sort order is determined by either `Group` or `SortOrder`, and there is nothing to tie these two together. In essence this means that your sort order is undefined, since the result is entirely dependent on what order the input is in, that is `sort(sort(List))` may not give the same result as `sort(List)`.

The way to fix this is to do something like:

```
private int objectCompare(String allowed, Comparable v1, Comparable v2) {
  if (v1 == v2) return 0;
  if (v1 == null) return 1;
  if (v2 == null) return -1;
  boolean c1 = v1.equals(allowed);
  boolean c2 = v2.equals(allowed);
  return c1 ? c2 ? 0 : 1 : c2 ? -1 : 0;
}
private int objectCompare(Comparable v1, Comparable v2) {
  if (v1 == v2) return 0;
  if (v1 == null) return 1;
  if (v2 == null) return -1;
  return v1.compare(v2);
}
public int compare(TemplateBean b1, TemplateBean b2) {

  // avoid null pointer exceptions
  if (b1 == b2) return 0;
  if (b1 == null) return 1;
  if (b2 == null) return -1;

  int cmp = objectCompare("UNATTACHED", b1.getStatusCode(), b2.getStatusCode());
  if (cmp == 0) {
    cmp = objectCompare("FIELDSIMPLE", b1.getRefRltshpTypeCode(), b2.getRefRltshpTypeCode());
    if (cmp == 0) {
      cmp = objectCompare("CUSTOM", b1.getRefRltshpTypeCode(), b2.getRefRltshpTypeCode());
      if (cmp == 0) {
        cmp = objectCompare("FUNCTION", b1.getRefRltshpTypeCode(), b2.getRefRltshpTypeCode());
        if (cmp == 0) {
          cmp = objectCompare(b1.getGroupCode(), b2.getGroupCode());
          if (cmp == 0) {
            cmp = objectCompare(b1.getSortOrder(), b2.getSortOrder());
            if (cmp == 0) {
              cmp = objectCompare(b1.getShortDescription(), b2.getShortDescription());
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return cmp;
}
```